# How to grep regex1 OR regex2?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I would like to grep (on ubuntu18.04) a every line that fits the pattern that "at least one of two number is greater than 0".

I found infomation about '|' usage in regex but I see it does not work here.

One of tried option:

```
grep -E "Foo:[1-9]+ | Bar:[1-9]+" input
```

which returns:

```
Foo:1, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:1
```

and that is invalid cause it matches only `Bar:[1-9]+`

Input data:

```
Foo:1, Bar:0
Foo:1, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:0
Foo:55, Bar:0
```

Expected result in a solution:

```
Foo:1, Bar:0
Foo:1, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:1
Foo:55, Bar:0
```

Comment: Try `grep -E "(Bar|Foo):0*[1-9][0-9]*" input`. If you only need matching lines the last `[0-9]*` is redundant.

Comment: If the regular expression contains spaces, then so must the input data

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. That simplification looks interested. And yes - you are right about not needed `[0-9]*` here - I miss to remove it while trivialize the example.

Comment: Should mention that regular expressions are not really meant for mathematical calculations e.g. the inequalities you are attempting, they are more for matching character patterns. (I believe) Try looking into sed or auk for your purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the space after the number: there's no such space in your input data.

```
grep -E 'Foo:[1-9]|Bar:[1-9]'
```

gives the expected output.

It can be further simplified into

```
grep -E '(Foo|Bar):[1-9]'
```

Note that the `+` isn't needed: a number starting with 1-9 is already greater than 0 even if it's followed by 0 or by nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe add "+": `[1-9]+`

Comment: Great! I've lost on spaces around `|`. So `grep -E 'Foo:[1-9]|Bar:[1-9]'` is what I had in mind. The simplified solution looks interested, I will try to introduce it into my real case study.

Comment: @battlmonstr: Not needed in my opinion. Explanation added.

Comment: It's not needed but it does make GNU grep's colored output prettier (unless the input is `Foo:10`)

Answer (score 0):

On top of the **great** answer proposed by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba), where we have combined all the patterns in one regex, you have two other way to do this, more especially if you have many patterns combining them in one regex may not be the optimal solution.

**1) Use all the pattern on the command line**:

```
grep -e 'Foo:[1-9]\+' -e 'Bar:[1-9]\+' input
Foo:1, Bar:0
Foo:1, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:1
Foo:55, Bar:0
```

(note that you have to escape the `+` (`\+`) as we are using POSIX standard regex)

**2) Regroup all the patterns in one file**

```
$ cat patterns 
Foo:[1-9]\+
Bar:[1-9]\+
$ grep -f patterns input
Foo:1, Bar:0
Foo:1, Bar:1
Foo:0, Bar:1
Foo:55, Bar:0
```

or eventually

```
grep -f <(echo 'Foo:[1-9]\+'; echo 'Bar:[1-9]\+') input
```

if you do not want to have a file.

Same remark about the `+`: a number starting with `1-9` is already greater than `0` even if it's followed by `0` or by nothing at all.